# How to check a Fedora system if IPv6 is disabled or not?

Tags: linux, fedora, ipv6

I remember that some distribution installers asked in the past if IPv6 should be enabled or not. Perhaps the Fedora installer did (or does) it as well.

How do I easily check a Fedora system (>= 17) if IPv6 was enabled/disabled during the installation?

Or how do I check if the Fedora system is ready for IPv6 enabled routers?

Answer (score 7):

Use `/sbin/ifconfig` or `/sbin/ip a l` and look for any lines starting with `inet6`.

```
$ ip a l eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.5/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe00::000:00ff:febc:a0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 0):

`lsmod |grep -i ip` will show loaded IP-modules. If you see ipv6 modules parts are active.

If you see an IPv6-address as described by *skohrs* you are already able to configure an IPv6-address to an interface.

It does not matter what your cable is connected to (router, switch, crossover, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Test if the path /proc/sys/net/ipv6 exists.